# use eventEmitter.emit() in component's template

Tags: angular, components, eventemitter

### Edit

I had a `TemplateRef` referenced with the same name in the HTML template !

```
<ng-template #eventEmitter>
```

Sorry about that, still keeping the question to reference the error code.

#### Old question

I was trying to use in a component's template `something.component.html` the `emit()` method of an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) instance as

```
<div (click)="eventEmitter.emit()">click me</div>
```

and defined in my component `something.component.ts` like

```
@Output() eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

and get the following error

```
"jit_nodeValue_3(...).emit is not a function"
```

I couldn't find any reference to this in [the doc](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) or [guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#custom-events-with-eventemitter) and was curious about this behavior, does someone have a real explanation ?

Comment: Here's an [example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exvzek?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up an `EventEmitter` on an `Output`:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    template: `<h1>Demo</h1>
    <button (click)="notify.emit('hello')">Notify</button>`
})
export class DemoComponent {
    @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Subscribing to the event:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<h1>App</h1>
    <demo (notify)="receiveNotification($event)"></demo>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    notifications = new Array<any>();

    receiveNotification(notification: any) {
        this.notifications.push(notification);
    }
}
```

Full [example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-event-emitter?file=app/hello.component.ts)